# C++: Error outputting a custom hash key value from unordered_map to std::cout

Tags: c++, hash, unordered-map, ostream

I am trying to build an `std::unordered_map` with a custom type as a key. The custom type is a simple `std::vector<double>`. The idea is that it will function as a convenient container for 2D points on a grid. Everything is working correctly except for outputting the hashed key. Here is a sample I put together to illustrate the idea:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>
#include <chrono>

namespace std
{
    template<typename Container>
    struct hash {
            std::size_t operator()(Container const& v) const
            {
                return boost::hash_range(v.begin(), v.end());
            }
    };
}

int main()
{

    std::unordered_map<std::vector<double>, double> test;

    unsigned long t = (unsigned long) std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    std::srand(t);
    for (uint i = 0; i < 100 ; ++i)
    {
        double d1 = i/200.0;
        double d2 = i/200.0;
        std::vector<double> v({d1, d2});
        test[v] = d1;
    }

    std::cout << "Size:" << test.size() << std::endl;
    for (const auto& it : test )
    {
        std::cout << it.first << ":" << it.second << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The hash specialisation template is courtesy of another SO thread. The trouble is that g++ spits out the following error when I try to compile the above:

```
cannot bind 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream<char>&&'
   std::cout << it.first << ":" << it.second << std::endl;
                   ^
```

It is obvious that it stumbles on `it.first`. The code compiles and runs correctly if I remove `it.first`. I understand that the output will *not* be a vector of doubles. I did look around SO for quite a while, but I couldn't find a definitive answer on how to `std::cout` the hash value from an unordered map with a custom key type. Any feedback will be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Edit:

Thank you everyone for your input. This was my first encounter with non-primitive types as hashed keys, so I had the wrong idea about how the key/value pairs were stored (I assumed that the hashed value is the key, whereas in fact it is the actual custom type).

Comment: If the key is always a vector of length 2, then a pair or tuple might be more efficient.

Comment: Well, I want to make it independent of the vector size so I can create a coordinate system of any dimensionality (perhaps usually 1 through to 4).

Comment: That's so *not* how you specialize `std::hash`. `it.first` is a `const vector<double>`, so there's no `operator <<` for it. Call the hash function yourself on it if you need the value.

Comment: @T.C. I am not sure why you consider this specialisation of `std::hash` incorrect - would you please elaborate? As far as I can tell, this is the standard way to specialise `std::hash`, but maybe I'm missing something. Other than that, following your advice, I inserted another loop to iterate over `it.first` and sure enough the values are printed fine, so thank you for suggesting that direction.

Comment: @nodialtone You are not writing a specialization; you are redefining the primary template. The only reason your code even compiles is because the particular standard library implementation you are using 1) leaves the primary template of `std::hash` undefined and 2) actually defines `std::hash` in `namespace std` and not an inline namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I am aware, there is no standard interface for exposing the hash value (as opposed to the hashing function) from `std::unordered_map`.

As you have seen, dereferencing a `std::unordered_map<Key,V>::iterator` yields something convertible to `std::unordered_map<Key,V>::value_type`, which in turn is a `std::pair<const Key,V>` representing a (key,value) pair, rather than a (hashed key,value) pair.

Correspondingly, `it.first` is giving you a `std::vector<double>` rather than a `std::size_t`.

Comment: The value type is `pair<const K, V>`.

Answer (score 1):

The `value_type` of an `unordered_map<K,V>` is `pair<const K, V>`. That's what you get when you iterate over it with a range-for. There's no `operator<<` overload for `vector`s, causing the error you see.

---

```
namespace std
{
    template<typename Container>
    struct hash {
            std::size_t operator()(Container const& v) const
            {
                return boost::hash_range(v.begin(), v.end());
            }
    };
}
```

This isn't a specialization of `std::hash`. It's a redefinition of the primary template, which in your case only compiled by pure happenstance. (The implementation will have to leave the primary `std::hash` template undefined, and will have to actually declare `hash` in the `std` namespace and not an inlined namespace. Your code [breaks up completely on libc++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/96d37590045ac212), for example.)

A specialization would look like

```
namespace std
{
    // full specialization
    template<>
    struct hash<Foo> {
    //         ^^^^^
            std::size_t operator()(Foo const& v) const
            {
                // ...
            }
    };

    // partial specialization
    template<typename T>
    struct hash<Bar<T>>{
    //         ^^^^^^^^
            std::size_t operator()(Bar<T> const& v) const
            {
                // ...
            }
    };
}
```

Note the explicit template argument list following `hash`. That's the indication that this is a specialization.

It is illegal to specialize `std::hash` for `std::vector<double>` anyway, because it doesn't depend on a user-defined type. Writing your own hasher is easy:

```
struct container_hasher {
    template<typename Container>
    std::size_t operator()(Container const& v) const
    {
        using std::begin; 
        using std::end;
        return boost::hash_range(begin(v), end(v));
    }
};
```

Note that I templated the `operator()` instead of the type itself - this makes writing the hasher type easier. The `using` followed by an unqualified call enables ADL for `begin` and `end`.

And then the definition of `test` becomes

```
std::unordered_map<std::vector<double>, double, container_hasher> test;
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, I understand now what you meant about the wrong specialisation. After your first comment, I continued to dig into this and ended up writing my own hash function, just as you suggested. I also decided that pulling in the boost dependency just for this is not worth it, so I re-implemented hash_range in my own function, which is then called when defining an `unordered_map` with a vector as a key. Thanks again for taking the time to clarify this, I feel like I learned a lot.